# UITextView setFrame not woking in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my UITableViewController Subclass

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TextCell";
    TextCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setContentText:[texts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 200;
}
```

In my UITableViewCell Subclass

```
-(void)setContentText:(NSString*)text{
    [self.cellText setText:text];
    CGRect frame=self.cellText.frame;
    frame.size.height=[self textViewHeightForText:text andWidth:frame.size.width];
    [self.cellText setFrame:frame];
}
```

self.celltext is created in storyboard

Problem like this:
First three of the textViews doesn't change their frame.
[image]

But when I scroll it down,the textViews below changed their frame.

[image]

Scroll back to top again,first three textView changed their frame finally.

[image]

**Why the first three textViews doesn't change their frame at first?
And how to solve the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, your cell's frame is not set yet. And later, when it is set, you don't adjust the frame again.

Like all layout in UIView subclasses, the best place to set frames is inside the `layoutSubviews` method.  This method will get called at the right time to set the subviews' frames.  Don't forget to call `[super layoutSubviews]` at the beginning.

Note that it may get called multiple times per instance (it may get called on rotation, or when the status bar frame changes, for example).  Therefore, try to keep expensive operations out of here.  Since calculating text sizes can be expensive, you may want to cache the result the first time you use it.